# Center an object between two objects with auto layout

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, interface-builder

I am laying out a calculator using Interface Builder and I ran into some issues with the layout of buttons.

I have 3 columns of number buttons, similar to most calculators, and I had no problem placing the left and right columns as the auto-layout feature of Xcode snapped them in the correct distance away from the edge of the window on the left and the operator buttons on the right; however, there was no automatic help for centering the middle column of buttons between those two.

I can eyeball it pretty well but I really prefer to have everything perfectly aligned. Is there any way to center a button between two other UI objects like this? here is a picture of the layout:

[image: Calculator Layout]

Comment: I assume you've seen this? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place all the buttons in their own View.  Place the view where you want the buttons.  Then you could align the left buttons to the left of the view, align the right buttons to the right of the view, and finally center the middle buttons.   Then adjust your view you made accordingly.  I did something very similar.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Based on what I know, this is the only solution that can be done using only Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it would work. Could you please explain (or link me to somewhere that explains) how to do a view like this? I'm really new to cocoa.

Comment: When using IB you can drag a view from the right hand side.  Position it where you want it and size it to however big you want.  Then you can place your buttons in the view.  Since you already have your buttons created, you can place the view, then on the left side of the screen, where you can slide out the outline of your storyboard, you can drag the buttons to under the new view you created.  Once the buttons are in your view, you can then do all the aligning.

Comment: If you move the buttons this way, you may have to rearrange then in the view after you move them in the organizer.  Or you can just place your view, make new buttons and then hook them up to all your actions.

Comment: Would I use a Custom View object for this? If I do, I still run into the same problem, but just vertically with trying to space out the 4 rows evenly.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes you will run into the same problem.  Your best bet would be to after aligning everything like previously mentioned, you could select say the 4, 5, & 6 button and pin their centers.  But you will have to eyeball it.  There is no constraint that I am aware of that centers something.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It doesn't seem like Apple to overlook something like that, but I guess I'll work around it.

Comment: Yeah, they should have a constraint that says center between two other items.  It would be very helpful.  I am sure you might be able to accomplish something like that with all the new constraints and how some take precedent over others, but I myself am still working on all that!  Best of luck with your class.